# Getting incorrect element's height() in $(window).resize handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, height

I am getting incorrect `div.height()` in `$(window).resize` handler.

Pseudocode:

```
var div = $('#someDiv');

div.html('');
div.css("height", "auto");

div.append( '<img src="1.jpg" style="float:left;" height="100" width="100"></img>' );
div.append( '<img src="2.jpg" style="float:left;" height="100" width="100"></img>' );
div.append( '<img src="3.jpg" style="float:left;" height="100" width="100"></img>' );
div.append( '<img src="4.jpg" style="float:left;" height="100" width="100"></img>' );
...

// I am loading the next after previous is loaded (onload)
// after last image is loaded:
console.log( div.height() );  // height is correct


$(window).resize( function(){
   console.log( div.height() );  // height is incorrect
});
```

Is it possible that the DOM doesn't update the div's height before I am getting it?

If the answer is yes, is there some event I could listen for?

//EDIT

Massive thanks to @adeneo for the jsfiddle.

I added the resize handler and it looks like it is working fine in my desktop chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/eUUrh/2/

Comment: Post your code please...

Comment: Added some code, please let me know if you need more

Comment: you might want to look at something like `$('#someDiv img').load(function(e) { console.log($('#someDiv').height()); })`. It's possible you're getting the height call split seconds before the images are finished loading, thus giving you a failed reading. Also, you can't get the height of a div element not attached to the DOM. You need to attach it to the DOM to start with like `var div = $('#someDiv').appendTo($('body'))`

Comment: @SpYk3HH I forgot to mention that I am actually getting the .height() after last image is loaded (onload). And I load the next after previous is loaded. So in theaory they all should be loaded before I get the .height(). The div is attached to the DOM beforehand.

Comment: 4 appended images with 100px height is 400px height, no need for a function to check =p

Comment: @johnSmith this is just a simplified version for the purpuse of this question.

Comment: Appending images to a div doesn't give the div a size, the images just overflows, so the height is still 0, so what you're getting is correct. To force the div to adjust, set `div {position: relative; overflow: auto;}` in your CSS and you'll get the correct height.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eUUrh/

Comment: Are you saying it worked ?

Comment: @adeneo I do apologize, I just realized that this is a problem in $(window).resize handler, not after the images load. Updated the question.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for the jsfiddle, it works. I will have to find what the reason was. Looks like it was something else I did wrong.